# Visual Studio Setup Project with Environment Variable Path

Tags: windows-installer

How can I set the target dir of a Visual Studio setup project to the folder in environment variable VS100COMNTOOLS?

So I want the files to be installed in %VS100COMNTOOLS% with a Visual Studio setup project.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

using $(VS100COMNTOOLS) might work.